# Where can i find realistic (maybe opensource) programming projects?

Tags: open-source, project

Right now, I'm losing track of my programming practice and have never been in real programming environment (large project). I want to keep up my skills, but I can't initiate any projects of my own. For example, I thought up of making a simple web browser, but I have absolutely no idea of how to create it via programming. I always wonder how they could make some idea comes alive into program, and I want to gain such knowledges. However, I don't know where to start this practice.

PS: Any programming language is preferable, but it would be great if it is a popular language (it would benefit my future career)

Comment: Are you looking for *task descriptions* or actually *implemented projects*?

Comment: Ideally, I would want an unfinished project with task to be done, but any would be fine at this point, because I think my current skills wouldn't allow me to initiates any sort of my own project yet

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sourceforge.com is filled with open source projects you could check out and/or participate to.